# FormArray de 2 niveles

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Que tal gente estoy tratando de llenar un formulario con su informacion previamente guardada, el formulario tiene 2 FormArray, al momento de querer editar el producto, este no me permite crear el segundo nivel de los FormArray y no se por que, lo he intentado de varias maneras pero no lo he conseguido.

Dejare el enlace de [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uczmbb?file=src/app/app.component.ts) por si alguien me puede ayudar e indicarme cual es la manera correcta de hacerlo.

la informacion que carga en uno de los productos a editar es el siguiente

```
"size": [
    {
        "size": 27,
        "stock": 14
    },
    {
        "size": 25.5,
        "stock": 0
    },
    {
        "size": 25,
        "stock": -9
    }
],
"description": "<p>Texo aqui</p>",
"color": "#f44336",
"price": 1111,
"image": "storage/o2dRZkGpci.jpg"
```

El formulario debe llenarse con name y code, el primer FormArray se llena con description, color, price e image y el segundo FormArray se llena con size (stock y size)

se deberia ver como en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo size y stock no se crean y se muestra de la siguiente manera (Notese que faltan los campos de stock y size que tiene el json)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Igual pega tu código de la pregunta aqui para que sea mejor aceptada. Que parte del código te falla?. Revisando el código todo parece funcionar (por los menos eventos).

Comment: @Legna gracias por tu tiempo, veras, al momento de que se ejecuta y llena los campos, no crea el segundo FormArray... es decir, no crea o carga la informacion de stock y talla, permiteme actualizar mi pregunta para explciar mejor mi problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despues de haberme partido la cabeza encontre la solucion! La dejare a continuacion por si alguien mas llega a tener el mismo o similar problema que yo

```
buscarProd(guid: string) {

    this.spinner.show()

    this.guidEditar = guid;

    this.productosService.getProductData(guid).subscribe(

      resp => {

        if (resp.status == 'Ok') {

          this.spinner.hide()

          this.editando = true;

          resp.producto.infoProduct = JSON.parse(resp.producto.infoProduct)

          var infoProduct = resp.producto.infoProduct

          var infoSize: any = []

          for (let index = 0; index < infoProduct.length; index++) {

            infoSize.push(infoProduct[index].size)

          }

          for (let index = 0; index < infoProduct.length; index++) {

            infoProduct[index].size = this.formBuilder.array([])

          }

          let control = <FormArray>this.formEditProduct.controls.infoProduct;

          let controlSize: any

          infoProduct.forEach((element: any, indexA: number) => {

            control.push(this.formBuilder.group(element))

            controlSize = control.at(indexA).get('size') as FormArray

          })

          infoSize.forEach((elementSize: any, indexB: any) => {

            for (let index = 0; index < elementSize.length; index++) {
              
              this.sizesEdit(indexB).push(this.formBuilder.group(elementSize[index]))
              
              
            }

          })


          this.formEditProduct.patchValue({

            code: resp.producto.code,
            name: resp.producto.name

          })

        } else {

          this.spinner.hide()

        }

      },

      error => {

        this.spinner.hide();

        this.iziToast.error({

          id: 'error',

          title: 'Error',

          message: 'Ha ocurrido un problema, intentelo de nuevo.',

          position: 'topRight',

          transitionIn: 'fadeInDown'

        });

      }

    )
  }
```

se que puedo eliminar varias lineas de codigo que no se necesitan y se pueden hacer en una sola, pero ese no es el tema ahorita. Agradezco a los que se tomaron el tiempo de leer mi pregunta. saludos y exito para todos!